# How to Install OpenCV2.0 in Mac OS 10.6.1 (Snow Leopard)

Tags: macos, opencv, osx-snow-leopard

I am not a Unix guy, so I have been trying to install openCV 2.0 for days with out success.
I just downloaded the opencv library form sourceforge from this page:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/
Does any one know the exact unix terminal commands for installing it?

please don't say "go to google", I already did. 
I found this:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide and this
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port
but the explanations are not very good for unix beginners.

installations always fails in the end.

It would be great if I can make a framework.
for example OpenCV.framework from the current source, So I can use it with Xcode, and Cocoa easier.

thanks

I did:

downloaded it.
extracted it.

```
cd Downloads/OpenCV-2.0.0
./make_frameworks.sh
```

and got this  when linking all the .o files.

```
mv -f .deps/saving.Tpo .deps/saving.Plo
mv -f .deps/logger.Tpo .deps/logger.Plo
mv -f .deps/index_testing.Tpo .deps/index_testing.Plo
libtool: link: (cd .libs/lib_clapack.lax/lib_clapack_floatstore.a && ar x "/Users/nacho4d/Downloads/OpenCV-2.0.0 3/build_i386/3rdparty/./.libs/lib_clapack_floatstore.a")
../libtool: line 961: cd: .libs/lib_clapack.lax/lib_clapack_floatstore.a: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [lib_clapack.la] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mv -f .deps/flann.Tpo .deps/flann.Plo
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
Creating universal Framework
=============================================
cp: build_ppc/OpenCV.framework: No such file or directory
lipo: can't open input file: build_ppc/OpenCV.framework/OpenCV (No such file or directory)
Done
```

!

Do I need to do something before running the shell script?

**EDIT**:
For the interested, I wrote a post on how to install and use OpenCV 2.1.1 on Macs here: 
http://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.com/2010/07/blog-post.html

Comment: I updated the question with the error i have when running the shell script.

Comment: I have a small post how to install OpenCV 2.1.1 in Macs.  http://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.com/2010/07/blog-post.html

Comment: I am getting opencv@2 has been disabled because it is not supported upstream!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just solved it.
In fact there is a bug somewhere, because if your path contains a space shell scripts will fail.

for example.

```
$pwd
/Users/nacho4d/Downloads/OpenCV-2.0.0 3
$./make_frameworks.sh
```

this will fail because current folder "OpenCV-2.0.0 3" has a space.

It took me many hours to realize this.
;(

Regards

Comment: For the interested: I have a small post how to install OpenCV 2.1.1 in Macs.  http://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.com/2010/07/blog-post.html 2.1 uses Cocoa. Hence works better on macs.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem compiling on Snow Leopard too, but was able to get it to work by following the  instructions at: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port

The only modification I had to make was also to disable ffmpeg inside of ccmake

> The GNU autotools methods (make &&
>   make install) are being outdated.
>   Volunteers to edit this section?
>
> mkdir opencv/build cd opencv/build
>   cmake .. ccmake .
>
> If you are on Snow Leopard, hit 't' to
>   toggle advanced mode. Set
>   CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/usr/bin/g++-4.0"
>   and
>   CMAKE_C_COMPILER="/usr/bin/gcc-4.0"
>   and then continue with the following
>   steps.
>
> Hit 'c' to configure. Hit 'g' to
>   generate the config file and exit
>   ccmake.
>
> make -j8 sudo make install
>
> If you hit the following build error:
>
> /Users/awagner/Developer/opencv2/src/highgui/grfmt_tiff.cpp:292:
>   error: ‘fmtSignTiffII’ was not
>   declared in this scope make[2]: ***
>   [src/highgui/CMakeFiles/highgui.dir/grfmt_tiff.o]
>   Error 1 make[1](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port): ***
>   [src/highgui/CMakeFiles/highgui.dir/all]
>   Error 2
>
> you can get the build to complete by
>   commenting out line 292 of
>   src/highgui/grfmt_tiff.cpp and running
>   make again. (This probably breaks
>   something in TIFF export, but the
>   build at least completes)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR of the link nacho4d posted:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fksSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb)"
brew install opencv
```

and after about 30mins of crunching, you should have OpenCV installed.

...

However, if you get an error from brew when its trying to install opencv then read this:
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/6424#issuecomment-2333585 and edit the brew recipe with:

```
export EDITOR nano # optional, but for novices nano is easier than vim
brew edit opencv
```

then run `brew install opencv` again.