# Using OpenCV 2.2 on MAC OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, opencv

I had tried to use openCV 2.2 on Mac OS X 10.6.6, I follow the instruction on http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port and [How to Install OpenCV2.0 in Mac OS 10.6.1 (Snow Leopard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512594/how-to-install-opencv2-0-in-mac-os-10-6-1-snow-leopard). I install it through macport. Everything seems OK during installation.

But when I follow the step by step instruction to use it, it just appear a lot of error like this:

[image]

I do not know what's wrong with is. Can anyone tell me the reason?

I just include the opencv.hpp and the main function just return 0.

Thank you all.

Comment: Post your code and the actual errors

Answer (score 0):

You can install OpenCV in your MAC using MacPorts. Works fine for me and its so easy to install and upgrade.

I didn't work with Xcode but i know that there is an option to compile OpenCV to use it with Xcode.
[Link](http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/opencv-snow-leopard/)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the following libraries to your project:

- libopencv_core.dylib
- libopencv_highgui.dylib
- libopencv_imgproc.dylib